# Ubuntu Software Center is only showing installed apps

Tags: 10.10, software-center

I have problem with Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 10.10. I have this

[image]

But i want USC like here:

[image]

As you can see I am from Russia, and I'm sorry for my bad english. What should I do to return my Ubuntu Software Center back to normal. (At first screenshot USC shows me all packeges that installed at my PC. At first screenshot USC shows me only installed apps.)

Comment: >At first screenshot USC shows me only installed apps
At second screenshot sure.

Answer (score 1):

click on Upper icon[softwares] it will show all applications in your repositories. Check is your /etc/apt/sources.list  ok? Then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Or you can generate sources.list from here for you distribution

http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: Oh... I did that. And I still see only packages in my Ubuntu Software Update :\

Comment: select  first option of USC (left side) then take a screen-shoot.

Comment: Here is it http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/4259/25509006.png

Comment: now search an un-installed application (right top side) or you can check using categories(click on icons ). Installed apps will have marked green on the right side. 2nd option (left side) is Installed apps. So it shows only installed applications.

Comment: if you can not find any option to install or uninstall then run this on terminal. sudo apt-get update  If this will not solve your problem then paste the output of this command:  cat /etc/apt/sources.list